# Set Task Scheduler "Configure for" parameter from command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to create task in Task Scheduler from Command Line using this command:
`SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC ONLOGON /TN "TaskName1" /TR "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"`

After executing this command, when I open my task in Task Scheduler, in properties `Configure for` parameter is set to `Windows Vista, Windos Server 2008`.

Is there a way to create a task having `Configure for` parameter set to `Windows 10`?

Comment: It a compatibility thing and only affects the DIALOG not the tasks. _For computers that are running Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, or Windows Vista, you can restrict the options displayed to those that are also available in previous operating systems. Doing this does not configure the task or the preference item to run on earlier operating systems._ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd851678(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks

Comment: @user12431753 this simply isn't true. If you were to add a task to run during LOGON of a specific user in windows 10, and the "configure for" is set to vista, the task will not run at logon.